# How can I put a login page on my website using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a login page for my website, but whenever i try to run it, it just downloads the file and shows me the code. I've tried using form action.

I have a .php extension, but nothing works. The PHP works perfectly fine on localhost, but I'm trying to add it to my website.

Here's an example: Facebook, Google, Paypal, they all have login and sign up places. I'm trying to make one of those, but when I use PHP without localhost, absolutely nothing happens.

I started PHP a few days ago, so I have a small understanding of web servers and how to use them. My main question though is: How do I add PHP to my website. Below is my login site, and if you click on the `login.php` link, it just downloads.

[My Login Site](https://login-harhar.netlify.app/)

Comment: Yelling "NOTHING WORKS!" doesn't help us to help you. We need to see what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers cannot read .php files. A .php file should go through a pre-processor before it is turned into HTML and sent to the the browser.

Typically the pre-processing work is done by the server. The `localhost` you mentioned mimics a server-like environment on your computer (eg. Turns your computer into a local server). When you access `localhost`, the browser sends a request to the server, which is created locally on your computer, and the server processes your .php file into a browser-readable HTML file and then returns it.

Read more here and try to make your server be able to run php: https://www.dummies.com/programming/php/how-php-works/